# Deleting a partition on USB stick

Tags: 13.04, usb

From disks I am trying to delete a partition from my USB stick. I am getting this error:

```
Error deleting partition /dev/sdc1: Command-line `parted --script "/dev/sdc" "rm 1"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Error: Invalid partition table - recursive partition on /dev/sdc.
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

Trying to format gives this error instead:

```
Error synchronizing after initial wipe: Timed out waiting for object (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

How do I get rid of this partition so I can put a plain FAT32 one instead?

Comment: I ended up using gparted and using the create new partition table option in the menus. The disk now works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using gparted and using the create new partition table option in the menus. The disk now works.

Answer (score 1):

If there's only one partition, you can start fresh with a new partition table.

From Disks, select your USB stick, press the button on the right top corner of the window (the one with the gears) and choose *Format disk...*

When asked, choose the option *Compatible with all systems and devices* option on the *Partitioning* dropdown.

After that, you should be able to add a new FAT32 partition easily.